# Trouble getting user data inside vue-router from composition

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I'm very new to vue.js, I am currently working on my final assignment for university.

I'm trying to get information of my user into my router, this works fine on my usual pages/components, but the techniques used on those files don't seem to work here. I've tried reading through some of the documention for router and composition, but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. This is my latest attempt as earlier I was not using `setup()` and getting the error; `inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.`

The problem is occuring with "useAuth," I'm not getting any data, my `console.log(isAdmin)` is displaying 'undefined,' this should be a boolean true/false.

Router code:

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Dashboard from "../pages/DashboardSDT.vue";
import Events from "../pages/EventsSDT.vue";
import Results from "../pages/ResultsSDT.vue";
import Admin from "../pages/AdminSDT.vue";
import Settings from "../pages/SettingsSDT.vue";
import Login from "../pages/LoginSDT.vue";
import Register from "../pages/RegisterSDT.vue";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import useAuth from "../composition/useAuth";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Dashboard",
        component: Dashboard
    },
    {
        path: "/Events",
        name: "Events",
        component: Events
    },
    {
        path: "/Results",
        name: "Results",
        component: Results
    },
    {
        path: "/Admin",
        name: "Admin",
        component: Admin,
        meta: { onlyAdminUser: true }
    },
    {
        path: "/Settings",
        name: "Settings",
        component: Settings,
        meta: { onlyAuthUser: true }
    },
    {
        path: "/Login",
        name: "Login",
        component: Login,
        meta: { onlyGuestUser: true }
    },
    {
        path: "/Register",
        name: "Register",
        component: Register,
        meta: { onlyGuestUser: true }
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})



router.beforeEach((to, _, next) => {
    const isAuth = !!getAuth().currentUser;
    const isAdmin = useAuth.admin;
    console.log(isAdmin)

    if (to.meta.onlyAuthUser) {
        if (isAuth) {
            next()
        } else {
            next({ name: "Login" })
        }
        // } else if(to.meta.onlyAdminUser) {
        //     if(isAdmin) {
        //         next()
        //     }
        //     else {
        //         next({name: "BasicUser"})
        //     }
    } else if (to.meta.onlyGuestUser) {
        if (isAuth) {
            next({ name: "Dashboard" })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    } else {
        next()
    }
})

export default {
    setup() {
        return {
            ...useAuth()
        }
    },
    ...router
}
```

useAuth code:

```
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import { computed } from 'vue'

export default function useAuth() {
    const store = useStore();
    const { state } = store;

    const error = computed(() => state.user.auth.error);
    const isProcessing = computed(() => state.user.auth.isProcessing);
    const isAuthenticated = computed(() => store.getters["user/isAuthenticated"]);
    const user = computed(() => state.user.data);
    const admin = computed(() => state.user.data.admin);

    return {
        error,
        isProcessing,
        isAuthenticated,
        user,
        admin
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vue-router's index file is not like a vue component file and does not have a setup() function.  I've never tried but it's unlikely you can use composable functions either, especially when using vue composition API functions like `computed()`

You **can** however import the vuex store and access all it's state, getters, etc. like you want.

```
import store from '/store/index.js'; // or wherever your store lives
```

Then inside your router guard

```
const isAuthenticated = store.getters["user/isAuthenticated"];
const isProcessing = store.state.user.auth.isProcessing
// ...etc
```